# How to use countif with or?

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, how do I use an `or` in `countif`? The following does not work:

```
=countif(F7:F36, "no or open")
=countif(F7:F36, "no" or "open")
```

The first returns zero and the second `#ERROR`

I'm looking for "no" or "open" in a single column. Both values may exist in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- COUNTIF doesn't directly support OR in criterion argument. You could just use `+` or a complex arrayformula(not shown):

  ```
  =COUNTIF(F7:F36,"no")+COUNTIF(F7:F36,"open")
  ```
- You can also use inbuilt sql:

  ```
  =QUERY(F7:F10,"Select count(F) where F matches 'no|open'")    

  =QUERY(F7:F10,"Select count(F) where F ='no' or F='open'")
  ```